# "Airport-friendly" suspenders (braces) with AIT

Tags: planning, tips-and-tricks, airport-security, x-ray-machines

I regularly wear [these suspenders](http://www.suspenders.com/everyday-suspenders/underups/no-buzz-und-xl/) with "airport-friendly" plastic clasps, designed to be worn under your shirt.  However, I will be traveling to an airport that used Advanced Imaging Technology (AIT) full-body scanners, and I wanted to get an idea of what to expect.  Depending on the answers, I may just leave them off and pray my pants stay up until I can get to a restroom, which is a tall order given my body shape.  Assuming I opt to leave them on:

- Do they trigger an alert?
- If so, am I better off requesting a pat down from the beginning?
- If I get a pat down, will they make me remove them anyway?
- I am traveling with my five year-old daughter.  How can I keep a pat down from affecting my ability to keep an eye on her?

Comment: I assume they would look like an explosive belt under the scanner  anyway, you are over thinking it IMO.

Comment: Why would suspenders trigger an alert? Do belts trigger alerts?

Comment: @pnuts Even in full-body scanners? I must admit i have never been through one.

Comment: A better comparison than a belt would be a bra. Having caught a glimpse of the output screen of the nude o scope when it saw my glasses on the top of my head or a credit card in my pocket, I can report it doesn't "detect" a bra without underwires and is unlikely to detect this. But if it does, a pat down or removing your shirt will resolve anyone's concerns, right? There's no reason for anyone to separate you from supervising your child while they check that.

Answer (score 10):

You're overthinking it a bit, and it'll likely be no problem at all.

As per the [product description](http://www.suspenders.com/everyday-suspenders/underups/no-buzz-und-xl/), they're airport safe.  So you have two possible options, depending on what the airport uses.

- metal detector - according to the product, it won't go detect them anyway. So you're through and happy.
- t-wave detectors *might* show it, but for example, two nights ago I was shown my scan in the t-wave and it showed liquid around my chest (I was sweating from carrying a backpack), but didn't show my belt.  So even then you're probably fine.

Worst case is that they detect some amount of metal.  They'll either ask you to remove your 'belt' or whatever you might have. This happens so often it's ridiculously routine for them.  You could either remove them then and rescan, or they'll request a patdown instead.  It usually happens within yards of the detector, so your daughter will still be close by, and takes seconds.

I suppose worst case they somehow get it into their head even if you show them, that you're a risk for some weird reason - at which point you might get taken into a room to remove them, but even then they're not going to separate you from your family. My aunt was recently taken aside in an airport, and her husband was allowed in with her.

But realistically, assuming the suspenders do what they claim and don't set off anything, you're going to pass through in seconds and be on your way to a coffee at the gate :)

Other stories from people who took suspenders:

- [TSA wanted them to unhook just one side](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/practical-travel-safety-security-issues/1231321-suspenders-question.html) and stated normally suspenders, even with metal, aren't picked up.
- [Probably the 'worst' I could find](http://milepoint.com/forums/threads/suspenders-keep-you-in-suspension.4478/) - with the passenger being a bit of a jerk to the scanners, and still being treated well and friendly with a quick pat down.

Answer (score 5):

It's been a couple years and I've been through the airport several times with these.  This question is still getting attention, so I thought I would answer with my actual experience.

- Yes, they alert the full-body scanners.  Every single time.
- No, they don't recognize them as suspenders and just let it pass, like the comment of the lady with the bra guessed.
- Yes, they require me to endure a pat down.  Every single time.
- I've had no issues keeping an eye on my daughter during the pat downs.
- Yes, I'm still trying to figure out a way to keep my pants up while holding both hands over my head.